# Decoding a file using a while loop

Tags: python

I need to move through this text using the askii value of the first letter, followed by an equation, and the move ahead to the next charcter repeating the process. The text is:

```
H fsaevt r pee  stnc u le a n
;iul
awl   leyr eehsd  phst- ol ogw 
usn 
h.o .t.  .wnr  
a snngHle.H  eh ad t aoo r  e gaoa, Me nehfor  d   y t iH  
ehada ollo 
ve oe vmels sldhhh t
rt  r1ri r s   w2m
lMthe u s3ord 
  wpn!!!
```

At the end of my program, I sould have an output file that reads

```
Hello world 1 2 3!!!
```

I am tasked to do this using a while loop without the 'with open' command.

This is the code I have so far, I have the value of the first character but I am unsure how to proceed.

```
def findNext(char):

    X = ord(char)

    if X >= 48 and X <= 57:

        value = X-40

    elif X >= 64 and X <= 90:

        value = X-60

    elif X >= 97 and X <= 122:

        value = X-90
        
    else:

        if X%2 != 0:
            value = X+1
        
        else:
            value = X+2

    return value
        



def decode(inputFile):

    file = open(inputFile, 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()

    while file[0:]:
        
        firstline = file[0]

        firstLetter = firstline[0]

        moveAhead = findNext(firstLetter)
        
    
'''
Code below is for tests
'''

        print(nextLetter)

decode('helloworld.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Here's working code. I use a string instead of files, but you can modify that.

```
enc = """H fsaevt r pee  stnc u le a n
;iul
awl   leyr eehsd  phst- ol ogw 
usn 
h.o .t.  .wnr  
a snngHle.H  eh ad t aoo r  e gaoa, Me nehfor  d   y t iH  
ehada ollo 
ve oe vmels sldhhh t
rt  r1ri r s   w2m
lMthe u s3ord 
  wpn!!!"""

def findNext(c):
    x = ord(c)
    if c.islower():
        return x - 90
    elif c.isupper():
        return x - 60
    elif c.isdigit():
        return x - 40
    else:
        return x % 2 + 2

def decode(msg):
    index = 0
    result = ""
    while index < len(msg):
        result += msg[index]
        index += findNext(msg[index])
    return result
    

print(decode(enc))
```

Output:

```
Hello world 1 2 3!
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP's full criteria can be simplified to :

*(pseudo-code below not necessarily python-compliant)*

```
x = ord(c)

if (c < "A" or "Z" < upper(c)):
    return x - 40 if (int(c) or c == "0") else x - x % 2 + 2
else:
    return x - (60 if c < "_" else 90)
```

(or the very hideous one-liner of)

```
x-(40 if int(c) or c=="0" else 30*(("_"<c) + 2) if c.isalpha() else x % 2 - 2)
```